# Do oracle database servers use a license key?

Tags: database-administration

I installed oracle Linux and oracle database on a test server using the media on the OTN. I noticed that no key was required.

My question is this: On a production environment at some point do I have to type a key?

Comment: This took me 20 seconds when I did a [Google](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_licensing) search on the subject.  **There isn't a license key**

Comment: Thanks! I did Google too before posting but I was looking for an "official" response and I did not find it at first.

Comment: I linked to an **semi-official response** a oracle wikipedia website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No keys are required for Oracle database software. Also be careful with what the OTN Development License (the one you read and clicked 'I agree' before downloading the software) actually covers you for... This isn't an official response but I've been dealing with Oracle licensing for 14 years now.